# Returning an object from a function in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a small program in which I have a global function overloading the operator `+`:

```
class Box {
    public:
        Box (int, int);
        Box (const Box&);
        ~Box ();
        int get_width() const;
        int get_length() const;
    private:
        int width;
        int length;
};

Box operator+(const Box& a, const Box& b) {
    int w, l;
    w = a.get_width() + b.get_width();
    l = a.get_length() + b.get_length();
    return Box(w, l);
}
```

In the function `operation+`, I have returned an object of class `Box`, as the object is not instantiated via operator `new`, the object is allocated on stack, isn't it?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Box a(100, 200);
    Box b(101, 202);

    Box c = a + b;
    cout << "width: " << c.get_width() << "; length: " << c.get_length() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In my `main` function, I tried to add 2 box `a + b`, and print the size of box `c`. It turns out that the object `c` has persisted, which means it's not removed from the stack after execution of function `operator+`. Or, the object `c` is in fact allocated in heap ??

I'm confused, anyone who could explain this to me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to your code.  If you have a function like the following

```
Box foo() {
    auto box_one = Box{};
    auto box_two = Box{};
    return box_one + box_two;
}

int main() {
    auto box = foo();
    // use box
}
```

The local variable in this `foo()` function starts off in the stack for the function (see last paragraph below for more) and is copied (again see below) to the variable `box` which lives in the stack for `main()`

The lifetime of the `box` variable in `main()` is tied to the surrounding scope, which in this case is the duration of `main()`.  And the object is allocated on the stack for the function `main()`, which is where it lives.

What happens in most optimizing compilers (pre C++17) and in all standard conforming compilers after C++17 is that the original `Box` variable that is returned from the `foo()` function is placed directly where it should be in the callee's stack, so `foo()`s return object is in `main()` stack from from the beginning (assuming it's called from `main()`)  This process is known as [elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Comment: Thank you for your help Curious, as you can see, I have also declared a copy-constructor for my class `Box`, and I have printed something inside the constructor. But when I run the program, the copy-constructor isn't invoked since nothing is printed. Is this also a result of the optimization?

Comment: Yep! Try and compile with -fno-elide-constructors. In c++17 this will not make a difference however

Comment: Yes! I have tried the option `-fno-elide-constructors`, and now the program does call the copy-constructor. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

What happens is basically that *two* `Box` objects are created: One in the `main` function and one in the `operator+` function. The `Box` object in the `operator+` function is ***copied*** into the object in the `main` function. Then the object in the `operator+` function is destructed, leaving you with the object in the `main` function.

A modern optimizing compiler do skip some of the steps mentioned above, most notable it will only create a *single* object as part of its [*return value optimizations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (creating only a single object and not copy anything is called [*copy elision*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), a term you will come in contact with sooner or later when programming in C++).

Comment: Thank you for your help.